# how i can give full width to responsive images

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've a website
http://hotelshimlahill.com/demo/
the sldier image size is 800x400
but you can see height is too much,I want to make the slider images responsive with the full width without loosing height.
please inspect and tell me asap.

Comment: `please inspect and tell me asap.` Like it :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Hi! Just use the following css rule to obtain the flexible width and height of an image**

```
.item img {
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner {
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
}
```

[image]
Hope the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following style for image:

```
<img style="height:auto; width: 100%;" src="abc.jpg" alt="IMAGE" >
```

Hope it works.

Regards.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, your question is how to limit the height of the image when it is scaled to full width?

One solution could be to set a fixed height for it (perhaps a `max-height`). That can be done using ie `height: 200px`, but that would force the image to always has that size vertically even as the image scales horizontally, distorting/stretching the image.

To prevent that you can use a `div` tag with a background image rather than an `img` tag. When the photo is placed as a background image we have better options for controlling its size:

```
<div style="
  background-image: url(images/slide1).jpg;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
"></div>
```

That should result in a block with an image stays at 200 pixels high, while preserving photo ratio by cutting off parts of the photo that grows outside the block.